# MediaPlayer mp.stop() not stopping

Tags: android

I have a music which I want it to be as a background music for the game I made.
I want it to stop when score becomes empty in order to start another one.
But it does not stop by using `mp.stop();` !
My code:

```
public class countgame extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.countgame);     
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(countgame.this, R.raw.game);
    mp.start();
    final ImageView i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final ImageView i2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

 i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {                        
                        incorrect();
                    }
                   });
       }
 public void incorrect(){

     final ImageView score = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i3);
     if ( score.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score3).getConstantState())){
            score.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.score2);
        }
      else if ( score.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score2).getConstantState())){
        score.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.score1);
        }
      else if ( score.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score1).getConstantState())){
          score.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty);

                 MediaPlayer m = MediaPlayer.create(countgame.this, R.raw.game);
                 m.stop();//here is the problem
                MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(countgame.this, R.raw.gameover);
                mp.start();
     }
}
```

Comment: probably because you instance a new mp object, and then try to stop that one. Try bonnyz answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
    public class countgame extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

            MediaPlayer mp;        
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.countgame);  
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(countgame.this, R.raw.game);   
                mp.start();
                final ImageView i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                final ImageView i2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

                i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {                        
                        incorrect();
                    }
                });
            }
            public void incorrect(){

                final ImageView score = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.i3);
                if ( score.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score3).getConstantState())){
                    score.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.score2);
                }
                else if ( score.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score2).getConstantState())){
                    score.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.score1);
                }
                else if ( score.getBackground().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score1).getConstantState())){
                    score.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty);
                    mp.stop();//here is the problem
                    mp=MediaPlayer.create(countgame.this, R.raw.gameover);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Does this happen at startup or when you click the imageView?

Comment: On the startup but I solved it :D
It works When I define  MediaPlayer mp before oncreate, and put mp = MediaPlayer.create(countgame.this, R.raw.game); on on create .
Thank you a lot